# User defined variables in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a wee bit of trouble calling a variable in phpmyadmin using the SQL query window.

I am still just learning the ropes so this is very simple. I believe it's just a small syntax or quote issue.

What I am trying to do is:

```
SET @var1 = Value (Does it need quote marks after "=" or not?)

SELECT * From `Table` WHERE 'Column' = @var1      (Same question about quote marks)
```

This seems just stupid simple.   I did a search and just couldn't quite find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you are using a reserved word and wanted to use it as fieldname, use double quotes(single quotes doesn't work, it's for string), it's ANSI SQL-compliant. And besides, backtick is not stackoverflow-friendly, you'll not be able to use them explaining the codes inside of sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value contains a string, you have to use quotes around it, otherwise you don't. But you should not quote your column name! So:

```
SET @var1 = 'stringval';
SELECT * From Table WHERE Column = @var1;
```

Comment: K good to know.   We have now moved past the syntax error and I am getting this:    #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: And I just checked and none of my stuff is using utf8_unicode.   It's all utf8_general

Comment: Problem solved.   I just had to change a couple settings.   Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

You dont need quotes:

```
SET @var1 =10;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `column` = @var1 //should work
```

Or you could do:

```
SET @var1:='somename';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `somefield`=@var1
```

See: [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Believe you just helped me with two reasons why it wasn't working.  I wasn't using a semicolon after the "SET" command.    And after reading the link you have I think my value isn't compatible.  The value I am trying to use looks like '10-12001'

Comment: if thats string then you could use something like in the added answer